# Weird behavior - wxPython Events

Tags: python, wxpython

I have this following piece of code. It is working sometimes, it is not the other time.

```
   def OnReset(self, event):

    self.reset_pump.Disable() # Disables the button so it is clicked
    self.WriteToController([0x30],'GuiMsgIn') # Sends the reset command
    self.flag_read.set()
    self.tr.join()
    time.sleep(2)
    start = time.time()
    self.offset_text_control.Clear()
    print "Helloin reset"
    self.gain_text_control.Clear()
    self.firmware_version_text_control.Clear()
    self.pump_rpm_text_control.Clear()
    self.pressure_text_control.Clear()
    self.last_error_text_control.Clear()
    self.error_count_text_control.Clear()
    self.pump_model_text_control.Clear()
    self.pump_serial_number_text_control.Clear()
    self.on_time_text_control.Clear()
    self.job_on_time_text_control.Clear()

    #self.MessageBox('Pump RESET going on Click OK \n')
    # Having the above step is useful
    print time.time() - start
    #self.ser.close()
    wx.CallLater(3000, self.CalledAfter, [event,])

def CalledAfter(self, event):
    self.tr = threading.Thread(target=ReadData, name="ReadThread", args=(self.ser, self.flag_read))
    self.tr.daemon = True
    self.tr.start()
    self.reset_pump.Enable()
```

What it does is When I click the Reset button on my GUI, it has to clear certain text fields on the GUI. It has to clear it, only after joining the self.tr thread.

Once it clears, it will execute the command wx.CallLater(3000, self.CalledAfter, [event,]). Which then starts a new thread again.

Apparently The .Clear() command is working very at a non consistent level, it is working some time, not working the other times, and working again.

Any idea why this might happen would be very helpful.

Comment: are you sure that Clear() is being called and the program isn't delaying at tr.join()? I doubt the problem is with the Clear method and would almost guarantee is related to ReadData or some other code not shown here.

Comment: What do you mean by being called? If you mean the tr.join is blocking, it is not. Because if it blocks, I would not be able to do the print commands I have in the code.

Comment: what happens if you call print(self.offset_text_control.GetValue()) immediately before and after Clear()?

Comment: Well for the before it is printing the value, after the clear, it is not printing any value. The code is clearing my GUI unconsistently,  once it is doing it, once it is not. And both the times, no value is printed for the print statement after the clear command.

Comment: So it looks like its clearing it consistently, just not updating how its displayed. If you call Refresh() on each text control or on the parent window does it update?

Comment: Same thing, I used refresh and update too.

Comment: How about if you do SetValue('') instead of Clear()

Comment: No, I cannot do that, The main purpose of this event is When The user clicks reset button on my GUI, this event will get executed. Everything gets cleared. Then a new thread (wx.CallLater) starts again, which again sets the value of those text fields.

Comment: you cant set the value to an empty string ""?

Comment: Looks like that is the only way; What do you think the root cause is?

Comment: I have no idea, those methods are implemented in C and apparently update the UI in different ways

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a difference in the way SetValue and Clear update the windows. Calling `SetValue("")` seems to be a suitable workaround to this behavior.